# macOS How to turn on airplay automatically on setup

Tags: macos, command-line, airplay, automation

I have a Mac mini, and I use it without wired monitor .

Every time, I connect to it with my old Macbook by screen sharing, and turn airplay on, mirroring the screen to a portable monitor. then close the macbook and begin working with Mac mini. ( of course I use bluetooth mouse and keyboard)

My questions is, how to turn on airplay automatically on setup - especially if I can use the command line to automate this?